# Closure reason - "RDBMS Not Specified"

Tags: feature-request

Day after day we see many questions that do not have a RDBMS tagged, which got me thinking (a miracle, I know) - Why don't we have a custom closure reason of "RDBMS Not Specified" added?

Comment: How would that be different from unclear + a comment about the missing (R)DBMS?

Comment: @dezso My laziness

Answer (score 4):

We can only have five active close reasons, and we are at that limit now.

You can always add a custom close reason when you vote to close. We do review those from time to time to see if there is a need to change one of the existing standard reasons.

If specifying the database is crucial to answering the question, I would have thought that the "unclear what you're asking" reason would suffice.

Related: [Why is RDBMS Type not a required field on this exchange?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1309)

Suggestions about improving the initial tags and new-user question experience:

- [Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634)
- [Let's Plan the Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285889)

Having better questions in the first iteration seems preferable to adding a new close reason.

Answer (score 1):

Because [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql)

[sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) indicates the question is about the language, not any specific RDBMS.

Comment: You mean it _should_ indicate that, right? ;)

Comment: good point, @dezso - when I just re-read my answer, I almost laughed out loud.  I thought to myself, "if only that were true".